# How to automate InstaSafe vpn login using `Keyboard` module in Python?

Tags: python, scripting

I am writing a python script to Automate InstaSafe login.
But while running my code, I am getting the following error.

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 21, in <module>
    keyboard.write("myPassword@123")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keyboard/__init__.py", line 854, in write
    scan_code, modifiers = next(iter(entries))
StopIteration
```

Here is my Python Script:

```py
import os
import keyboard
import time

# Launch InstaSafe Application
os.system("gtk-launch InstaSafe.desktop")

# Press `Tab` then `Enter` and wait for 1 sec
keyboard.press('tab')
keyboard.press('enter')
time.sleep(1)

# Write user name in `Username: ` field
keyboard.write("myUserName")

# Wait for a second then go to next tab
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('tab')

# Write password in `Password: ` field
keyboard.write("myPassword@123")
```

What my code is doing?
**Explanation:**

1. Launch InstaSafe Application

[image]

2. Press `Tab` then `Enter` and wait for 1 sec.

   It will click on connect button shown in the above image. and this window pops up.

[image]

3. Write the user name in the `Username:`  field.

[image]

After this, it is not going into the next tab `Password:` .
And also, throwing an ERROR at this line.

```py
keyboard.write("myPassword@123")
```

Can someone help me to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming because `keyboard.write("myPassword@123")` has capital letters which is not acceptable by function write. The function handles only one case at a time. You can also try diffrent methods to input the word here is one of my solution.

Try this Python Code I used:

```
def keyboardEnter(keyword):
        for letter in keyword:
            if letter.isupper():
                key = f'shift + {letter.lower()}'
                print(key)
                keyboard.press_and_release(key)
            else:
                print(letter)
                keyboard.press_and_release(letter)
        return

def connectVpn():
    userName= "myUserName"
    pwd = "myPassword@123"

os.system('gtk-launch InstaSafe.desktop')

time.sleep(6)
keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
time.sleep(3)
# keyboard.press('enter')
time.sleep(3)
keyboardEnter(userName)
time.sleep(5)
keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
keyboardEnter(pwd)
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press_and_release('tab')
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press_and_release('Enter')
```